# setCellProps in mui with multiple conditions

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I have a data-table not in a class extending the React.Component like I have seen in some examples.  I am trying to setCellProps based on content such as the following:

If utilization is <= 50  then color green and padding 5, else if utilization >50 then color red and padding 5.

I have not been able to find any examples of how to do multiple conditions and if it can be done without extending react...

```
<code>
const rowContents = teams.filter((team) => !!utilizations[team.id])
                          .map((team: Team) => ({
                                team,
                                summary: utilizations[team.id].getSummary(),
                              }))
                              .map(({ team, summary }) => (
                                [team.name,                                          // name
                                 summary.utilization.toLocaleString()])       

const columns = [
    {
      name: "Team",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       setCellProps: () => ({ style: { padding: 5 }}),
       setCellHeaderProps: () => ({ style: { padding: 5 }}),


     }
    },
    {
      name: "Utilization",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       setCellProps: () => ({ style: { padding: 5 }}),
       setCellHeaderProps: () => ({ style: { padding: 5 }}),

     }
    }

return (
    <MUIDataTable
    title={'Teams'}
    columns={columns}
    data={rowContents}
    options={
              {"draggableColumns":{"enabled":true},
               "pagination":false,
               "selectableRows":"none"}
            }
    />     
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do this so wanted to post here in case someone else struggles with this:

Here is an example of how to do conditional styling in datatables...

```
{
      name: "Utilization",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       setCellProps: (cellValue:string, dataIndex:integer, rowIndex:integer) => {
        return {
          style: Number(cellValue) > 50  ? {color: "red", padding: 5} : {color: "black", padding: 5}
        };},
       setCellHeaderProps: () => ({ style: { padding: 5 }}),


     }
```